# Mysql : Cannot set Transaction Isolation level

Tags: mysql

Mysql version :5.7.41-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Cannot modify the isolation level into READ COMMITTED needed for a Drupal10 database:

Running these commands as root

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> show variables WHERE Variable_name LIKE "%isolation";
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name         | Value           |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| transaction_isolation | REPEATABLE-READ |
| tx_isolation          | REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

or adding

```
 'init_commands' => [
    'isolation_level' => 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED',
  ],
```

to the database array in settings.php

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: how do you know that the init_commands is not working?

Answer (score 2):

SET GLOBAL changes the global value but does not change your *current session's* value. Your current session copied values from the global settings at the time the session started. Sessions don't inherit subsequent global setting changes (with a few exceptions, e.g. `read_only`).

You have two alternatives to fix this:

- Use SET SESSION instead of SET GLOBAL.
- Close and reopen your connection, which will start a new session and copy the current global values.

Comment: even the SET GLOBAL will not last across a server restart; better to set it for each session or in the config files (or in mysql 8, SET PERSIST)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I was surprised that running SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED worked perfectly from the mysql prompt but not from the Drupal settings php.
The reason was the presence of 2 blocks of database array, a first one at the top of the file containing the init_commands isolation_level...`and a second block where the init_commands was missing. (and silly overwriting the previous setting)

Comment: This is more of a comment to the answer. Please post it as a comment and not an answer.